# PHP Unset multiple array except what I want

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to unset all items, that I don't want to show in a drop-down except that I need, for a security reason.

This is the code from my controller...

```
$options['']    = '--Please Select--';
$query = $this->departments->get('department_name');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $options[$row->id] = $row->department_name;
}

return $options;
```

And this is my view

```
echo form_dropdown('department_id', $options, '','');
```

I don't want that admin to change his/her department. Only super admin can change that. Thus I need to unset all the options except the department he/she is in.

For instance, the current admin `department_id = 5`. Then how to unset all other options `(1,2,3,4,6,7)` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the obvious answer is don't include those options in the array.

Comment: $this->departments->get('department_name')->where('id',5)

Answer (score 0):

You just write code in your controller for delete that records.

-> Check current user role is super admin or not.

-> If role is super admin so you can find current admin department.

-> And write query for finding data from database not equal to admin_department_id.

-> And delete all data and return new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add disabled property when option variable created.

For this, you have to check user type and based on this you create option list and when user type is not super admin, you can add selected and disabled property when department_id id 5.

For this , i shared one example with you.

```
echo form_dropdown('department_id', $options, 'default', 'disabled="disabled"');
```

I hope it will help you.